# Firefox always show development tools

Tags: firefox

Is there a way to always show developer tools when opening a new tab in Firefox?

In the past I always used Firebug, where I used to just detach a window, and it just automatically targetted whichever tab I was on.

However since it's now discontinued, I'm using Firefox's built in developer tools and am having an issue where every time I open a tab, I have to manually enable developer tools, then refresh the page every time.

This is fine most of the time (if not a little inconvenient), however if you are posting data, the extra refresh of the page can cause duplicate submission problems etc.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution?